# Blender for mincing bell pepper?

Tags: blender

I tried to grate bell pepper on a grater and it doesn't really work.

It worked on a meat grinder but I prefer some kind of smaller device.

The blenders work best for fruits, they only have the blades at the bottom of the container. Is there some types of blenders that work well for bell peppers? Probably having blades in the middle too, not only on the bottom.

Or other simple machines - manual or electric.

Later edit: This one seems to be what I need:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lH3xKp3tk0g&t=35s

Does it have a name? How can I find one on Amazon?

Comment: That's a mini food processor/chopper.

Comment: I don't know where the information "blenders work best for fruits" comes from, but it is untrue. Blenders work equally well for fruits and vegetables, there is no difference there (and it would be strange if there were, since the fruit/vegetable distinction is not about the physical structure of the food). A difference that might be interesting for you is: blenders are meant to produce a thick liquid/puree, while food processors/choppers are meant to produce small bits of food.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The device pictured at the beginning of the video you attached is called a food processor. There are several sizes and ranges of quality.  Just type "food processor" into the Amazon search bar.

Comment: An issue came up once before that there are some languages that don’t make a distinction between ‘blender’ and ‘food processor’. (I think it was ‘mixie’ in Indian) so you might need to use an English language search engine that doesn’t do synonym expansion.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like "food chopper" is also a good term for searching such machines - for example this one - https://www.amazon.com/Electric-Processor-Stainless-Titanium-Chopping/dp/B07H4K499J/